# Android 6.0 permission and target

Tags: android

I need to add the new permission things to an old project, which still has to stick to ant building. The following is the previous configuration:

project.properties:
    `target=android-23`

AndroidManifest.xml:
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />`

I changed AndroidManifest.xml to
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />`
but found that on my Android 6.0 phone it still warns me that my app is not compatible with the lastest Android permission requirements. And it behaves as if it really targets pre-23.

So is there any solutions?

Comment: You have 2 options: 1- Lowering the target API, using 22 or lower. 2- Implement the new permission system following this tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @MatPag I have implemented the new permission system in code and set the target to 23, but it still behaves like it targets lower.

Answer (score 0):

I just share the code to add check for permissions, which has been made mandatory procedure since Marshnmallow. For instance, I check for permission to access camera.

```
private void launchCamera() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MyActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            // Showing explanation to user to require permission

          // <Build a dialog here. Following shows how to handle dialog clicks>

            dialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Yes, user wants to give permission
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MyActivity.this,
                            new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            Constants.PERMISSION_CAMERA);
                }
            });
            alog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // No, user does not want to give permission now
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

        } else {
            // No explanation needed, requesting for permission now.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    Constants.PERMISSION_CAMERA);
        }

    } else {
        // Permission to get location has been granted already.
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.CAMERA_CAPTURE_REQUEST);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Camera is not found!");
        }

    }
}
```

Next we have a method to implement based on user's response provided to system dialog (which pops up just after our dialog).

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == Constants.PERMISSION_CAMERA ){
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            launchCamera();

        } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

                /*Here we have to show a dialog/ something else to show user why app requires permission. This is a good practice.*/

                // Handle dialog clicks again
               // Build a dialog here
                btnPositiveOfDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Yes, I want to give permission now after reading detailed message
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UserInfoActivity.this,
                                new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                Constants.PERMISSION_CAMERA);
                    }
                });
                btnNegativeOfDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // No, I still don't understand detailed message and want give permission away
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

            } else {
                // User checked 'Never ask again'
                // Build a dialog here
                btnPositiveOfDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Yes, go to app settings and manually enable settings
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        final Intent i = new Intent();
                        i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                        i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + UserInfoActivity.this.getPackageName()));
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                        MyActivity.this.startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
                btnNegativeOfDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // No, I don't want to go to user settings and give permission now.
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();

            }

        }
    }
}
```